# How do I get jwilder/nginx-proxy to work on Amazon ECS? I am getting a 503 error

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, jwilder-nginx-proxy

Here's my setup:

Docker Compose File for my wordpress site

```
version: '3'

services:

  wordpress:
    # image: wordpress
    image: 506641774060.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cashinyourpoints:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: secret
      VIRTUAL_HOST: cashinyourpoints.com

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret

    volumes:
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./dbData:/var/lib/mysql
```

Docker Compose file for my Nginx Proxy

```
version: '2'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
```

I run `ecs compose up` on both. However, when I try to go to http://cashinyourpoints.com I get a "503: Service Temporarily Unavailable" error. When I go directly to the container's ip I get the same error. And when I run the test command I still get that same error `curl -H "Host: whoami.local" 54.184.203.137`

My `ecs-cli ps` output

```
  Name                                              State                Ports                        TaskDefinition    Health
  9bf63a86-ae41-4c73-ad21-83f4adcbdfa6/nginx-proxy  RUNNING              54.184.203.137:80->80/tcp    aws-nginx-config:1   UNKNOWN
  a88c599b-8a88-41bc-b00f-ad57fc8df82e/wordpress    RUNNING              54.184.203.137:8081->80/tcp  cashinyourpoints:30  UNKNOWN
  a88c599b-8a88-41bc-b00f-ad57fc8df82e/mysql        RUNNING                                           cashinyourpoints:30  UNKNOWN
```

I read somewhere that this may be related to networking, but I couldn't figure out how to get the Amazon version of Docker networking started (Docker's network property is not supported).

I'm stuck at how would I create a subnet in the vpc model?